# Javascript Accordion changing img depends on if it is open or closed

Tags: javascript, accordion

I have the following problem. I want to create accordion and I want it change arrows depend if arrow is open or closed,  unfortunately I am alway getting error

** script.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at**
and then on click
** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement. **

```
let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
let i;
let arrowDown = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-down");
let arrowUp = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-up");


for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (panel.style.display === "none") {
      panel.style.display = "block";
      acc.firstChild.style.display ="block";
      acc.childNodes[1].style.display = "none";

    } else {
      panel.style.display = "none";
      acc.firstChild.style.display ="none";
      acc.childNodes[1].style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

when I click on accordion open and close is working good but it doesn´t change img

here is html

```
<button class="accordion">Detailed info <span>
                <svg class="arrow-down" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M0 7H16V9H0V7Z" fill="#5E636A"/>
                    <path d="M9 8.74224e-08L9 16H7L7 0L9 8.74224e-08Z" fill="#5E636A"/>
                </svg>
                    

                <svg class="arrow-up" width="16" height="2" viewBox="0 0 16 2" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M0 0H16V2H0V0Z" fill="#E0672E"/>
                </svg>
                     
                </span>
            </button>      
            <div class="panel">
                <h5>Vestibulum tellus urna, porta eu mi in, tincidunt ullamcorper nulla. Curabitur finibus ipsum a ex u ltricies porttitor in vitae sem. </h5>
                <p> Suspendisse sit amet nisl vel orci efficitur luctus. Curabitur ac risus viverra, egestas felis in, congue libero. Etiam fermentum, magna eget pellentesque vehicula, libero turpis vulputate nulla, at porttitor erat tellus sed risus. Nulla facilisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed at pulvinar libero. Pellentesque consequat ultricies imperdiet.</p>
            </div>

            <button class="accordion">Size chart<span>
                <svg class="arrow-down" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M0 7H16V9H0V7Z" fill="#5E636A"/>
                    <path d="M9 8.74224e-08L9 16H7L7 0L9 8.74224e-08Z" fill="#5E636A"/>
                </svg>
                    

                <svg class="arrow-up" width="16" height="2" viewBox="0 0 16 2" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M0 0H16V2H0V0Z" fill="#E0672E"/>
                </svg>
                     
                </span>
            </button>      
            <div class="panel">
                <h5>Vestibulum tellus urna, porta eu mi in, tincidunt ullamcorper nulla. Curabitur finibus ipsum a ex u ltricies porttitor in vitae sem. </h5>
                <p> Suspendisse sit amet nisl vel orci efficitur luctus. Curabitur ac risus viverra, egestas felis in, congue libero. Etiam fermentum, magna eget pellentesque vehicula, libero turpis vulputate nulla, at porttitor erat tellus sed risus. Nulla facilisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed at pulvinar libero. Pellentesque consequat ultricies imperdiet.</p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can deal with the handling of displaying the arrows and content.
You actually can access them through `this` whenever you click on your button. Therefore you can actually get your arrows through the `NodeList`. Instead of `document.getElementsByClassName` for the `.accordion` button, in this case it is better to use `document.querySelectorAll`.
I hope that this can help you to tackle your problem.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
   let arrowDown = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-down");
            let arrowUp = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow-up");

            for(let a= 0; a< arrowUp.length; a++){
             arrowUp[a].style.display="none";
            }
            


for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
        this.children[0].childNodes[1].style.display="inline";
                 this.children[0].childNodes[3].style.display="none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
       this.children[0].childNodes[3].style.display="inline";
                this.children[0].childNodes[1].style.display="none";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display:none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Detailed info <span>
         <svg class="arrow-down" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M0 7H16V9H0V7Z" fill="#5E636A"/>
                                <path d="M9 8.74224e-08L9 16H7L7 0L9 8.74224e-08Z" fill="#5E636A"/></svg>
                            <svg class="arrow-up" width="16" height="2" viewBox="0 0 16 2" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M0 0H16V2H0V0Z" fill="#E0672E"/>
                            </svg>
                            </span>
              </button>  

                
                       

             <div class="panel">
                  <h5>Vestibulum tellus urna, porta eu mi in, tincidunt ullamcorper nulla. Curabitur finibus ipsum a ex u ltricies porttitor in vitae sem. </h5>
                  <p> Suspendisse sit amet nisl vel orci efficitur luctus. Curabitur ac risus viverra, egestas felis in, congue libero. Etiam fermentum, magna eget pellentesque vehicula, libero turpis vulputate nulla, at porttitor erat tellus sed risus. Nulla facilisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed at pulvinar libero. Pellentesque consequat ultricies imperdiet.</p>
              </div>

                       

                 <button class="accordion">Size chart
                    <span>
                      <svg class="arrow-down" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M0 7H16V9H0V7Z" fill="#5E636A"/>
                                    <path d="M9 8.74224e-08L9 16H7L7 0L9 8.74224e-08Z" fill="#5E636A"/>
                                </svg>
                                <svg class="arrow-up" width="16" height="2" viewBox="0 0 16 2" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M0 0H16V2H0V0Z" fill="#E0672E"/>
                                </svg>
                      </span>
                 </button>   

               
                            <div class="panel">
                                <h5>Vestibulum tellus urna, porta eu mi in, tincidunt ullamcorper nulla. Curabitur finibus ipsum a ex u ltricies porttitor in vitae sem. </h5>
                                <p> Suspendisse sit amet nisl vel orci efficitur luctus. Curabitur ac risus viverra, egestas felis in, congue libero. Etiam fermentum, magna eget pellentesque vehicula, libero turpis vulputate nulla, at porttitor erat tellus sed risus. Nulla facilisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed at pulvinar libero. Pellentesque consequat ultricies imperdiet.</p>
                            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work ? I just tried in my browser and it is functioning properly. I just removed the `console.log` so that is not confusing.

Comment: Fixed snippet, I hope now it can give you some short of hint.